# truffle migrate stop at the first contract

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

When I tried to run **"truffle migrate"** with **geth** (private network), the migration process stop at this point:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js                                         
  Deploying Migrations...                                                         
  ... 0xff148f4b640cc595a41b01ec6f43deb62542fe11df397079c6af2b4a13a5f9fd
```

how to solve it?

Comment: On which network your geth is connected ?

Comment: Launch a `geth attach` terminal and run `personal.unlockAccount(address, "password")` inside it. Do migration after unlocking that deployer account.